# Kohen aliyah during shiva

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, torah-service, sitting-shiva

If a kohen is in his shiva period, can he take the kohen aliyah if there is no other kohen present?  We had such a situation on Shabbat at mincha.  One ruling said that the kohen should take the aliyah in such a case, but on Monday at the Shiva house, the rabbi who was present (chabad) said he should not.

Comment: Why might he not be able to have the aliya?

Answer (score 5):

Shaarei Efrayim ([shaar 1 sif 23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34320&st=&pgnum=46) and [shaar 8 sif 109](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34320&st=&pgnum=261)) says that he should not be called up in the first place and should be asked to leave before the kriah. If he was called up already, then on weekdays he can't take the aliya but on Shabbos he can.

Answer (score 5):

The Shulchan Aruch - Yoreh Deah [סימן שפד - האבל אסור בתלמוד תורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_60.html#HtmpReportNum0042_L2) says that:

> **ב** אִם הָאָבֵל (ב) כֹּהֵן, וְאֵין בב''ה כֹּהֵן אַחֵר, אָסוּר לוֹ לַעֲלוֹת לִקְרוֹת בַּתּוֹרָה.‏

Even of the mourner is the only Cohen, he cannot be called up.

The באר היטב however clarifies that in [סימן ת - דיני אבלות בשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_60.html#HtmpReportNum0058_L2) the Shulchan Aruch says that on Shabbat a mourner  called up to the Torah may go up, otherwise it would be a public display of mourning which is forbidden on Shabbat.

> וְאִם קָרְאוּ אֶת הָאָבֵל לַעֲלוֹת לַתּוֹרָה, צָרִיךְ לַעֲלוֹת, שֶׁאִם הָיָה נִמְנָע הָיָה דָּבָר שֶׁל פַּרְהֶסְיָא

The באר היטב then brings the ב''ח that if he's the only Cohen there on Shabbat, he may be called up Ab initio, as the Shulchan Aruch there says:

> וְכֵן אִם הַכֹּהֵן אָבֵל וְאֵין כֹּהֵן אַחֵר בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, מֻתָּר לִקְרוֹתוֹ; אֲבָל בְּעִנְיָן אַחֵר, אָסוּר (הַגָּהוֹת מַיְמוֹנִי פ''ג מה''א)‏

This is the full text of the באר היטב:

> **באר היטב**  (**ב**) **כהן**. כ' הב''ח ותימא דבסי' ת' **בדין שבת כתב הרב דבאין שם כהן אחר אלא הוא מותר לקרותו** וכאן לא כתב כלום וכ' הש''ך דלק''מ דהכא טעמא דאיסורא דאבל אסור בד''ת אתא לאשמועינן ומדין אבלות בשבת לא מיירי אבל התם דמיירי בכל הסי' מדין איסור אבלות בשבת קאמר דמותר לעלות משום דאל''כ ה''ל אבלות דפרהסיא ואין אבלות דפרהסיא נוהג בשבת והכי משמע התם להדיא עיין שם עכ''ל: ‏