# Is shiva suspended during weekday davening?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, mourning-aveilus

This is a hypothetical designed to investigate a subtlety of practice and understanding, not elicit a halachic ruling.

I will be attending a morning shiva minyan on Monday. The mourner is a kohen and will be the only kohen present at the davening. I don't know if in that case he is supposed to get the 1st aliyah, but I have read [that](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/370617/jewish/The-Laws-of-Shiva.htm) "If he is called to the Torah by mistake, he may accept." So in this hypothetical, the gabbai mistakenly calls the mourner, who has the aliyah.

I also know that during a shiva, the tradition is not to open the conversation with the mourner or greet him:
"A mourner is forbidden to say hello or goodbye; likewise we do not say hello or goodbye to a mourner. We do not say "shalom," or any other greeting" (cited from Shulchan Aruch, YD 385:1 [here](http://www.beingjewish.com/cycle/nichum.html#N_10_)).

Generally, though, when someone receives an honor during services, such as an aliyah, it is proper to say [Yishar](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1197597/jewish/More-Power-To-You.htm) Kochacha (or some variant, depending on tradition/pronunciation).

But is that, as a greeting, inappropriate during a shiva? Is the mourner still sitting shiva while he is participating in the service (on a non-Shabbat/holiday) or are the laws suspended (if he is accidentally called for hagbah, can he sit down with the torah in a regular chair)?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60067/759 I see no reason the laws would be suspended during services. What sort of basis for that could there be? It's not Shabbat. Shiva doesn't just stop for no reason.

Comment: Re your last comment, Shiva shouldn't be different from Tisha BAv http://ohr.edu/holidays/tisha_bav/poetry_and_riddles/1103

Comment: As to the first question about suspending shiva, once the person has taken the honor, he is doing something generally not done as part of the shiva and it is allowed. In a sense, some aspect of shiva has been pushed aside. And if he sits in a regular chair after hagba then, again, some element of shiva is not there. Does this same aspect include how one can greet/react to that aliyah?

Comment: It seems you have four different questions: "Is shiva suspended during weekday davening?" "is [YK], as a greeting, inappropriate during a shiva" "Is the mourner still sitting shiva while he is participating in the service" "if he is accidentally called for hagbah, can he sit down with the torah in a regular chair" I recommend canning the extended hypothetical and asking about each component individually. That way, you can feel confident your case is addressed explicitly, people have a manageable amount of material to cover, and you might find some of the extension questions just fall away.

Comment: To start, why not just change this, to asking what the basis of the ruling of the Chabad article is and what the nature of the ability of the mourner's to accept the Aliyah is. Be sure to check out http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60067/759 first.

Comment: Partially because of the parallel drawn to hagba on 9th Av. Clearly one set of practices outweighs another. My question is about those parameters.

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment.

Comment: I would question whether yashar koach or the equivalent is a greeting.  It doesn't really open a conversation but, in my experience, is a formulaic saying with a formulaic response beyond which no further conversation follows.  It seems even more divorced from she'elat shalom than regular greetings like 'good morning'.

Comment: On sitting on a chair after getting hagba, it is possible that the mourner may sit on a regular chair at any time he is not receiving comforters.  Since obviously no one should be approaching him to comfort him while he sits holding the Torah, he may well be allowed to sit on a regular chair anyway, even aside from  the impracticality of rising from a mourner's chair with a Torah.