# Can an Avel read from the Torah?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, mourning-aveilus, sitting-shiva

While someone is sitting shiva, are they allowed to be a ba'al koreh and read from the Torah, or is that considered simcha?

Comment: Possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60078/759

Answer (score 1):

See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 219:3 [סימן ריט - דין אבלות בשבת ויום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0218_L2) that an Avel during Shiva should not be the Ba'al Koreh.

Whether this is simcha related is not mentioned.

> הַמְמֻנֶּה מֵהַקָּהָל לִהְיוֹת קוֹרֵא בַתּוֹרָה בְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת בְּשַׁבָּת וְאֵרַע לוֹ אֵבֶל, לֹא יֵלֵךְ בְּשַׁבָּת שֶׁבְּתוֹךְ שִׁבְעָה לְבֵית כְּנֶסֶת זֶה. כִּי אִם יִהְיֶה שָׁם, יֵש לְהִסְתַּפֵּק אִם יִקְרָא אוֹ לֹא‏

Comment: What's the Safek? It'd clearly be permitted as Avelut beFarhesia

Comment: BTW (for OP),when I was an *aveil*, my rav said that I  shouldn't read on Monday / Thursday either. However, there is obviously a different reasoning than public mourning, as one does express public mourning during the weekdays. I'll have to research this aspect a bit further.

Comment: @DanF - during the week an Avel is not allowed to learn (non-mourning-related parts of)   Torah. Krias HaTorah included; he can't even be given an Aliya.